# Next JS doesnt re render element when state changed

Tags: reactjs, next.js

i have a code where im fetching the image name

```
const [foundImg, setFoundImg] = useState(false)
var imgNames = []
---
axios.get('http://someapi.com')
.then(res => {
  imgNames.push(res.data)
  setFoundImg(true)
}.catch(err => console.log(err)
```

And i put this condition in the return / render

```
         { (foundImg === true) 
            ? itemImg.map( i => {
              return <div className="product--box">
                <Image width={50} height={50} src='/public/dummy.png' className='img'/>
              </div>
            })
            : null
          }
```

But the problem is, when the imagenames are fetched, the component doesnt re render. So it is still empty now. How can i make it so that this image are rendered when the fetching returns data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are storing **imgNames** as a local variable, and because it is not a state of react component, so that if you change **imgNames**, React wont recognize that you need to update the component.

Solution:

Change `var imgNames = []` become to `const [imgNames, setImgNames] = useState([])`

Then change `imgNames.push(res.data)` to `setImgNames(res.data)`

After the state changes, React will re-render the component for you

Comment: In addition, React doesn't support mutability so anything in the React state will have to follow an immutable approach.

Answer (score 0):

you should use imgNames.map() instead of item.Img.map()